# 64 bit applications in React Native

Tags: react-native

There is a lot of conflicting information regarding React Native and 64-bit applications. Can someone help determine the following:

1. Does React Native support publishing 64-bit applications built entirely in React Native (no native code)?
2. Is there any documentation on how to publish a 64 bit application using React Native?